# MySQL Query [ Two list ]

Tags: mysql

I have two table:

**˙ipban˙ There I store all banned ip's**

Structure:

```
IP
Reason
Date
```

**˙connections` There I store all connections(with information;IP,name,date etc)**

Structure:

```
IP
Name
Date
```

Admins have list of all IP Bans,and they can unban,etc..Now,i want that admin can click on IP,and he will get popup with all connections from clicked ip.

So I need to SELECT all banned IP + all connections from all banned IP.I don't know how to make query for it.

Sorry for my English!

Comment: give it a try at least. It is not that hard. `learning to fish` goes a long way.

Comment: Hi.I don't know where to start for this.I don't know what to use(I can't use Join because i have more connections from an ip from ipban table.So I want to select all conectinos from all banned ip.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you need join

```
select distint c.*,ipb.*
from ipban ipb  left join
 connections c   
 on c.ip=ipb.ip
```

Comment: Hi
Yes.I know for join.
Problem is that I have more connections from an ip from ipban table.There is not just one connection.So I want to select all connections from all banned ip.If you can undestand me.

Comment: is only ip need from both tables

Comment: IP need to be qual in both tables,yes..But i need all information

Comment: then check now please

Comment: I need to select all IP Bans...Connections are just aditional information...As I said :"Admins have list of all IP Bans,and they can unban,etc" I need IP list,but connections are aditional information...If you can't understand...no problem.I can't explain better because i don't speak English very well.Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @PaulCastellano im trying to help you , could you please share your two table sample data and what will be output from that